# Why does Get-TlsCipherSuite return null or zero field values for some ciphers?

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption, tls1.2

When I run Get-TLSCipherSuites on a Windows 2019 Hyper-V and VMware VM, I get something like this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-TlsCipherSuite

KeyType               : 0
Certificate           : RSA
MaximumExchangeLength : 1024
MinimumExchangeLength : 1024
Exchange              : DH
HashLength            : 0
Hash                  : 
CipherBlockLength     : 16
CipherLength          : 256
BaseCipherSuite       : 159
CipherSuite           : 159
Cipher                : AES
Name                  : TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Protocols             : {771, 65277}

KeyType               : 0
Certificate           : 
MaximumExchangeLength : 0
MinimumExchangeLength : 0
Exchange              : 
HashLength            : 0
Hash                  : 
CipherBlockLength     : 0
CipherLength          : 0
BaseCipherSuite       : 0
CipherSuite           : 0
Cipher                : 
Name                  : TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Protocols             : {}
```

This is just the 1st two entries on the list, but notice the 2nd entry has null or zero field values. I actually see this frequently on the Internet on articles about Get-TLSCipherSuites, but I have not seen an explanation.

If I reorder the cipher suites a particular way, the null/zero values are replaced with valid values, particularly for TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, in my case.

Why is this? Is the TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher valid and available for use when Get-TLSCipherSuote returns null/zero field values?

This is what I was expecting:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-TlsCipherSuite

KeyType               : 0
Certificate           : ECDSA
MaximumExchangeLength : 65536
MinimumExchangeLength : 0
Exchange              : ECDH
HashLength            : 0
Hash                  : 
CipherBlockLength     : 16
CipherLength          : 256
BaseCipherSuite       : 49196
CipherSuite           : 49196
Cipher                : AES
Name                  : TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Protocols             : {771, 65277}
```

Comment: @mklement0 Right O! My bad. It's been 10 years since my last question on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: :) Thanks for updating.

Comment: @Angrydot I can't fully answer your question but I tested on my windows 10 machine and ran into similar behavior. `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`  has 0, and empty values like what you have while running `Get-TlsCipherSuite`. However, specifically selecting it  ` Get-TlsCipherSuite -Name TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` populates it with values. I can't see how `Get-TlsCipher`  which returns all TLS Ciphers returns different values for the same thing than when specifically selecting one.